# PyQt remembering UI states/ items

Tags: python, pyqt, settings

I'm using a `QStackedWidget` where on Screen 1, I have a `QTreeWidget` with a list of items and Screen 2 has a few comboboxes and checkboxes. Double clicking on an item in the tree widget takes me to Screen 2. What I want to do is develop a way to remember chosen settings.

So for eg. if I double click on'*Item1*' in the treewidget, choose some options in the check and combo boxes in screen 2 and return to screen 1 and choose '*Item2*' wherein this time I choose a different set of combo items etc. On going back to the first screen again and double clicking on '*Item1*', I should restore the options I had previously associated with it.

Hope this makes sense. I needed help on the best way to do this and some code examples would be great.

Really appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you post your code for suggestions

Comment: My code is too big to be pasted here, wherein this query is just a small part of it. To show it for this post, I'll have to cut it down. ekhumoros answer below worked perfectly though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All tree-widget items have a [setData](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidgetitem.html#setData) method that you can use to store associated values, which in this case would just be a `dict` containing the settings.

To make saving and restoring the settings easier, it would be advisable to make sure all the checkboxes, comboboxes, etc have a common parent, and that they are all given a unique `objectName`. That way, it will make it easy to iterate over them:

```
    def saveSettings(self):
        settings = {}
        for child in self.settingsParent.children():
            name = child.objectName()
            if not name:
                continue
            if isinstance(child, QtGui.QCheckBox):
                settings[name] = child.isChecked()
            elif isinstance(child, QtGui.QComboBox):
                settings[name] = child.currentIndex()
            ...
        return settings

    def restoreSettings(self, settings):
        for child in self.settingsParent.children():
            name = child.objectName()
            if name not in settings:
                continue
            if isinstance(child, QtGui.QCheckBox):
                child.setChecked(settings[name])
            elif isinstance(child, QtGui.QComboBox):
                child.setCurrentIndex(settings[name])
            ...
```

To add the settings to the tree-widget item, you just need to do something like this:

```
    settings = self.saveSettings()
    item.setData(0, QtCore.Qt.UserRole, settings)
```

and to retrieve them, do this:

```
    settings = item.data(0, QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
    self.restoreSettings(settings)
```

But note that you may need to take an extra step here if you are using python2, because `data` will return a `QVariant`, rather than a `dict`. If that is the case, to get the `dict`, you will need to do this instead:

```
    settings = item.data(0, Qt.QtCore.Qt.UserRole).toPyObject()
```

Alternatively, you can get rid of `QVariant` everywhere but putting this at the beginning of your program:

```
    import sip
    sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)
    from PyQt4 import ... etc
```